# How to print a docx file to a printer using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, printers

I am trying to write a program in node.js that will allow the user to print a docx file to the printer.

anyone that can show me how its done in Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [node-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) module.

Here's example how to use it to print a file:

```
// use: node printFile.js [filePath printerName]
var printer = require("printer"),
    filename = process.argv[2] || __filename;

console.log('platform:', process.platform);
console.log('try to print file: ' + filename);

if( process.platform != 'win32') {
  printer.printFile({filename:filename,
    printer: process.env[3], // printer name, if missing then will print to default printer
    success:function(jobID){
      console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
} else {
  // not yet implemented, use printDirect and text
  var fs = require('fs');
  printer.printDirect({data:fs.readFileSync(filename),
    printer: process.env[3], // printer name, if missing then will print to default printer
    success:function(jobID){
      console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: printer is not a module, and when I change it to `require('node-printer')` printDirect is not a function.........