# What is the correct approach to print a PDF directly to the printer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, backend

How to use Node.js to print directly to the printer?

For example, send a PDF file directly to a printer, OBS: The printer is in the network shared.
Can I, for example, do an axios request with a file?

Comment: thru a browser? or thru something node is attached to?

Comment: thru native system, for example from nodejs (back-end) to a printer..

Comment: Does this help? [How to print a docx file to a printer using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817153)

Comment: i tried to use printer, but, the behavior dont works well with pdfs or images, only text, i need a pdf

Comment: @DarkAstolfo their github repo seems to have [examples](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/tree/master/examples)

Comment: Yep, but the example with pdf, dont works, the file isnt send to the printer :(